# VB.Net Hide a window through code (Not is .Net window)

Tags: windows, vb.net

I have a quick question:

Somebody have a code snippet to hide a window completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Along the same lines as your other question, you can use the handle of the window you want to hide and call the `ShowWindow` API function using 0 for nCmdShow will hide the window.

**Declaration**

```
 Private Declare Auto Function ShowWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Integer, nCmdShow As Integer) As Boolean
```

**Usuage**

```
ShowWindow(handle, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

use this `Me.Visible = False` or check this out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548(v=vs.85).aspx